# Adding multiple taxonomy terms to a node via code

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

I've been editing nodes in code (Drupal 8) like so:

```
$node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($nid);
$node->body->value = $body;
$node->title->value = $title;
$node->taxonomy_field->target_id = $value;
```

If the 'taxonomy_field' entity reference supports multiple terms, how do place them in the $node object? I have tried at least a dozen ways I found on other threads, but none worked. Either errors were thrown, of the code just silently failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object orientated way would be to use `appendItem()` from `FieldItemList`:

```
$node->field_tags->appendItem([target_id => '1']);
```

But as the field object provides an array interface you can add items to the field the same way as in a php array:

```
$node->field_tags[] = '2';
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question of assigning multiple terms, despite the syntax fix.

Comment: @AlxVallejo, the syntax in the question is fine but it overwrites the field item instead of adding it.

Comment: Still doesn't answer the question of assigning multiple ... do you have to `appendItem` for each individual term? I believe so, but I don't see how setting a single target_id to a taxonomy term is valid.

Comment: Yes, if you apply both code lines from my answer you have two more items in the field. Normally you probably want to use a loop, though. If you have already built an array with multiple items you can assign the entire array.

Answer (score 0):

$node->field_tags->appendItem([target_id => '1']); worked for me but
$node->field_tags[] = '2'; did not.